# intriguing standard errors for categorical predictors in mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, standard-error

I am looking at the influence of three within subject manipulations (Condition, group and delay - all contrast coded) on binary (yes/no) responses.

Given the repeated-measures design, I fitted a logistic regression model using the glmer function from the lme4 package.

```
glmer(ReachN~Cond+Gr14+Grsq+Gr23+D1+D23+Cond*Gr14+Cond*Grsq+Cond*Gr23+Cond*D1+Cond*D23+Gr14*D1+Gr14*D23+Grsq*D1+Grsq*D23+Gr23*D1+Gr23*D23+Cond*Gr14*D1     +Cond*Gr14*D23+Cond*Grsq*D1+Cond*Grsq*D23+Cond*Gr23*D1+Cond*Gr23*D23+(1+Cond+Gr14+Grsq+Gr23+D1+D23+Cond*Gr14+Cond*Grsq+Cond*Gr23+Cond*D1+Cond*D23+Gr14*D1+Gr14*D23+Grsq*D1+Grsq*D23+Gr23*D1+Gr23*D23+Cond*Gr14*D1+Cond*Gr14*D23+Cond*Grsq*D1+Cond*Grsq*D23+Cond*Gr23*D1+Cond*Gr23*D23|Participant), data = DataMR, na.action = na.exclude, family = binomial, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE))
```

The output seems rather odd. Standard errors for different predictors appear to be similar and most of all, they seem disproportionately high. Does this indicate a mistake ? How to interpret such high standard errors and how come some of them are so similar ?

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     3.013145  49.472843   0.061  0.95143    
Cond            1.989904  49.470848   0.040  0.96791    
Gr14           -8.942560  98.941839  -0.090  0.92798    
Grsq           -1.358774  49.470862  -0.027  0.97809    
Gr23           -2.530410   0.152060 -16.641  < 2e-16 ***
D1              0.674029  49.470085   0.014  0.98913    
D23            -0.075701  74.204760  -0.001  0.99919    
Cond:Gr14      -2.813013  98.941287  -0.028  0.97732    
Cond:Grsq      -1.292497  49.470709  -0.026  0.97916    
Cond:Gr23      -0.353312   0.120930  -2.922  0.00348 ** 
Cond:D1         1.018625  49.470011   0.021  0.98357    
Cond:D23        0.142895  74.204749   0.002  0.99846    
Gr14:D1        -2.197312  98.940017  -0.022  0.98228    
Gr14:D23        0.050433 148.409469   0.000  0.99973    
Grsq:D1        -0.744043  49.470030  -0.015  0.98800    
Grsq:D23       -0.117962  74.204744  -0.002  0.99873    
Gr23:D1        -0.252024   0.133036  -1.894  0.05817 .  
Gr23:D23       -0.001706   0.108879  -0.016  0.98750    
Cond:Gr14:D1   -2.377441  98.939965  -0.024  0.98083    
Cond:Gr14:D23   0.047423 148.409460   0.000  0.99975    
Cond:Grsq:D1   -1.379270  49.470013  -0.028  0.97776    
Cond:Grsq:D23  -0.156793  74.204748  -0.002  0.99831    
Cond:Gr23:D1   -0.070809   0.127303  -0.556  0.57806    
Cond:Gr23:D23  -0.137489   0.094452  -1.456  0.14549
```

Comment: Your model seems overly complex, are your sure that you need all these interaction terms?

Comment: It is indeed and I do not need them all but I wanted to be able to prove it so I included them.